# golang -Comparing two txt files

Tags: string, text, go, slice

I want to know the contents when file changed

there is a simeple txt file

```
textOne 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

and i change it to

```
textTwo 1,2,3,4,7,7,7,8,9,10
```

so 'One' and '5,6' changed to 'two', '7,7'

I can find things which changed by loop. but I wonder if there was some better way to check

Comment: perhaps a diff library? https://github.com/sergi/go-diff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of looping use standard third-party library, with small optimisation.

One of the library that I've used in past is [Go port of google-diff-match-patch](https://github.com/sergi/go-diff) (same library that @Not_a_golfer suggested in the comment.).

You can optimise this by first calculating `sha2` hash of two files, and if they are not the same, you can assume that they are changed, otherwise (probably) they are same, and skip the diff operation.

One drawback of this optimisation is that, because of pigeon-hole principle, it is possible theoretically to have same hash value, for different contents. But, the probability of happening that is quite small.

**EDIT (based on @elithrar's comment):**
Since calculation of hash for very large file, can be time consuming. You can calculate `sha2` in chunks (size depends on particular hash algorithm from `sha2` family). This enables you to bail out early, and improves speed.

Comment: You could also use a buffered reader to read chunks of a file (say, 4K blocks), hash them and compare. This avoids having to hash large files, improves speed (you bail out early) and should avoid collisions. SHA-2 should be suitable.

Comment: Also Rolling Hash functions are a thing, and so if you are going for maximum performance that's the way to go. I'd be surprised if the core algorithms haven't been implemented in Go yet.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash